# Creating an empty var gives me an error

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have an `enum` with 4 objects inside. I'm trying to create an **empty** variable that **will** point to a certain object in the `enum`.

```
enum Collection:Int{
        case First=1, Second, Third, Fourth
}
var myCollection : Collection

myCollection = Collection.Second // This will happen later on.
```

I get the following error at the classes name:

> Class 'MyClassName' has no initilizers

How can I fix that?

Comment: `var myCollection : Collection!` you have to set optional value.. `! or ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from your other question regarding this switch, implicitly unwrapping the variable gives you a (seemingly) odd error-message when using a switch-statement. (Which can be fixed with `switch myCollection as Collection` btw. ).

Anyway, to the question at hand it might make sense to expand your enum to include a `.None` value. and define the variable var

`myCollection : Collection = .None`

Comment: Thanks! 1 - Is `switch myCollection as Collection` the same as "`switch myCollection!`"  ? 2 - When doing `myCollection : Collection!` that works. Is there a benefit of adding the `.None` vs the !?

Comment: If you define it with the .None value and do not implicitly unwrap it (by using !) your `myCollection` var is actually of the type `Collection` and not the (different) unwrapped type. Also, being an enum it should be type safe from thereon.

Answer (score 0):

Change your property to optional

```
    var myCollection : Collection?
```

Or give it a default value

```
    var myCollection : Collection = Collection.First
```

If it is not optional or without a default value,it have to be initialized in initilizers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the instance property.

There are many way to fix that error. It depends on the situation.

```
enum Collection: Int {
    case First = 1, Second, Third, Fourth
}

var myCollection: Collection = Collection.First

myCollection = Collection.Second
```

If you want to set nil, use ?(question mark).

```
enum Collection: Int {
    case First = 1, Second, Third, Fourth
}

var myCollection : Collection?

myCollection = Collection.Second
```

Or (In this case, I used just init().)

```
enum Collection:Int{
    case First = 1, Second, Third, Fourth
}
var myCollection : Collection

init() {
    myCollection = Collection.Second 
}
```